# MySql join multiple select subquery

Tags: mysql, sql, join, subquery

-SOLUTION-

```
SELECT Table1.unvan, Table2.sayi FROM 
(SELECT id , unvan FROM unvan WHERE id IN 
(SELECT unvani FROM personel WHERE gorev_yeri IN 
(SELECT id FROM gorev_yeri WHERE il_id="34") ) ) AS Table1 
JOIN
( SELECT unvani as id , count(*) AS sayi FROM personel WHERE gorev_yeri IN (SELECT id FROM gorev_yeri WHERE il_id="34") GROUP BY unvani ) AS Table2 
ON Table1.id = Table2.id
```

### -EDIT-

### When I use join with as I get this error : #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AS table1

I have 2 query and I want join them.

[It is first.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m2rPw.png)

```
SELECT id
     , unvan 
  FROM unvan 
 WHERE id IN (SELECT unvani 
                FROM personel 
               WHERE gorev_yeri IN (SELECT id 
                                      FROM gorev_yeri 
                                     WHERE il_id="34")
              )
```

[It is second one.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4h0iv.png)

```
SELECT unvani as id
     , count(*) AS sayi 
 FROM personel 
WHERE gorev_yeri IN (SELECT id 
                       FROM gorev_yeri 
                        WHERE il_id="34") GROUP BY unvani
```

I need this:

unvan|sayi

--------|----

Comment: You really don't like the word JOIN, do you?

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Add some sample results from the two queries, and show us the combined result. (Well formatted text, please.)

Comment: Thanks for underestimate me about join. When I use join i get error like this : #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'table1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based from error provided

It should be like this:

```
SELECT `Table1`.unvan, `Table2`.id
FROM
(
    SELECT id
    , unvan 
   FROM unvan 
   WHERE id IN (SELECT unvani 
            FROM personel 
           WHERE gorev_yeri IN (SELECT id 
                                  FROM gorev_yeri 
                                 WHERE il_id="34")
          )
) AS `Table1`

JOIN

(
SELECT unvani as id
 , count(*) AS sayi 
 FROM personel 
 WHERE gorev_yeri IN (SELECT id 
                   FROM gorev_yeri 
                    WHERE il_id="34") GROUP BY unvani
) AS `Table2`

ON `Table1`.id = `Table2`.id
```

Answer (score 1):

(SELECT id
     , unvan 
  FROM unvan 
 WHERE id IN (SELECT unvani 
                FROM personel 
               WHERE gorev_yeri IN (SELECT id 
                                      FROM gorev_yeri 
                                     WHERE il_id="34")
              )
)table1

join

(
SELECT unvani as id, count(*) AS sayi FROM personel WHERE gorev_yeri IN (SELECT id FROM gorev_yeri WHERE il_id="34") GROUP BY unvani
)table2

on table1.id=table2.id;

Comment: When I use join i get error like this : #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'table1.

Comment: Add `SELECT * FROM` first of all. And, perhaps you need to do `as table1`.

Comment: Yeah, sorry I forgot, Add Select * from

Comment: Same error again : #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AS table1